# Javascript dynamic variable name in loop

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I can't figure out how to use dynamic variable in JS.. I have a list of ticker, some balances associated, and I want to display each 'balance sticker' in my loop, dynamically.
But it seems like it's not using the append I add to the variable at all?

```
var ticker = [CURRENCY1,CURRENCY2,CURRENCY3];
var balancesCURRENCY1 = 20;
var balancesCURRENCY2 = 30;
var balancesCURRENCY3 = 40;

for (var tick in ticker) {

  if (('balances'+ticker[tick]) != 0) {
    console.log(true);
  }     

}
```

Comment: Use an array instead. (You *could* use `eval`, but you really, really shouldn't. Dynamic variable names are quite a bad code smell.)

Comment: ugh - redesign, reformat and refactor - nothing good will ever come of any answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

To use dynmamic variables, keep the variableNames in an Object, whenever you create the variable name dynamically, refer the object to get the variable's value.

```js
var ticker = ['CURRENCY1','CURRENCY2','CURRENCY3'];
 
var allBalances = {
  balancesCURRENCY1 : 20,
  balancesCURRENCY2 : 30,
  balancesCURRENCY3 : 40

}

for (var tick in ticker) {

  if (allBalances['balances'+ticker[tick]] != 0) {
    console.log(true);
  }     

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to quote names in the array: `[CURRENCY1,CURRENCY2,CURRENCY3]`, otherwise they would be handled as variables.

Then you can access your dynamic names from `this` see the snippet below:

```js
var ticker = ['CURRENCY1', 'CURRENCY2', 'CURRENCY3'];
var balancesCURRENCY1 = 20;
var balancesCURRENCY2 = 30;
var balancesCURRENCY3 = 40;

for (var tick in ticker) {

  if (this['balances'+ticker[tick]] != 0) {
    console.log(
      ticker[tick], 
      'balances'+ticker[tick] + ' = ' + this['balances'+ticker[tick]],
      true
    );
  }     

}
```

Comment: What if I want to show the balancesCURRENCY1 value? I tried that but its returning "balancesCURRENCY1" and not the value..

    var ticker = ['CURRENCY1', 'CURRENCY2', 'CURRENCY3'];
    var balancesCURRENCY1 = 20;
    var balancesCURRENCY2 = 30;
    var balancesCURRENCY3 = 40;

    for (var tick in ticker) {

      if (this['balances'+ticker[tick]] != 0) {
        console.log('balances'+ticker[tick], true);
      }     

    }

Comment: @Vincent, `this['balances'+ticker[tick]]` returns the value.

Comment: I meant in the console.log(), im trying to get the value of each, but it says undefined even with this['balances'+ticker[tick]]

Comment: Thanks man! For some reason, this['balances'+ticker[tick]] is working here on stack overflow, but if I try it on other compiler its not. Do you know why is that? It says undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to maintain 2 parallel arrays

```
var ticker = ['CURRENCY1','CURRENCY2','CURRENCY3'];
var balances = [20, 30, 40];
```

or an array of objects:

```
var tickerInfo = [
  {currency: 'CURRENCY1', balance: 20},
  {currency: 'CURRENCY2', balance: 30},
  {currency: 'CURRENCY3', balance: 40},
];
```